# What is the asterisk alone in the parameter list?

Tags: ruby

I found this in a Module that is supposed to extend some other class:

```
module Somemodule
  def foo(*)
    do_something_funny
    super
  end
end
```

I understand `def foo(*args)` construct. What is the purpose of an asterisk alone?

Comment: this is just like as in C++ `int function(int){  }` likewise in ruby * works the same

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's similar to `*args` but you get no reference to the arguments. They are, however, passed as provided to any `super` invocation to the parent's constructor (or same-name method), as long as no explicit parameters are specified in the `super` call.

It is a nice way to convey that you do not intend to process the provided arguments in any way.